# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property in react JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Below is the Task component which renders an array of tasks.

```js
export function Task() {

    const tasks = useSelector((state) => state.tasks.taskArray);

    function handleOnDragEnd(result) {
        if (!result.destination) return;

        let items = [...tasks]; // also tried with tasks.slice() to obtain a deep copy

        let i = result.source.index;
        let direction = result.destination.index > result.source.index; 
                   // direction true means moving right & swapping

        while (i != result.destination.index) {
            if (direction) {
                let tempGlobalKey = items[i].globalKey;
                items[i].globalKey = items[i + 1].globalKey; // <<< here 
                items[i + 1].globalKey = tempGlobalKey;
                i++;
            } else {
                let tempGlobalKey = items[i].globalKey;
                items[i].globalKey = items[i - 1].globalKey; // <<< here
                items[i - 1].globalKey = tempGlobalKey;
                i--;
            }
        }

        dispatch(updateOrder(items));
    }

.
..
... so on
```

In the taskSlice, the updateOrder reducer is as follows // using redux-toolkit hence directly mutating state below

```js
export const tasksSlice = createSlice({
    name: "tasks",
    initialState: {
        taskArray: [],
        meta: {
            globalKey: 0,
            completedTaskStartIndex: -1,
        },
    },
    reducers: {
        updateOrder: (tasks, { payload }) => {
            tasks.taskArray = payload;
        },
    }
    ......so on
```

when drag ends and handle drag end is ran, the error comes on lines marked in code. The error message is

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'globalKey' of object '#<Object>'
handleOnDragEnd
src/containers/tasks/index.js:60
  57 |     i++;
  58 | } else {
  59 |     let tempGlobalKey = items[i].globalKey;
> 60 |     items[i].globalKey = items[i - 1].globalKey;
     | ^  61 |     items[i - 1].globalKey = tempGlobalKey;
  62 |     i--;
  63 | }
```

i know that state cannot be mutated directly hence i am updating the deep copy of the array and setting that as the new state which should ideally work. Will really appreciate if issue can be pointed out or if there is an alternative way i can achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using Redux, the purpose of the reducer is not to mutate the previous state, but to return a **new modified** state instead.

It sounds like a trivial difference but it isn't, since the previous state object is usually immutable depending on the framework and/or Flux implementation.

You can make it work by changing your reducer's code to this one

```js
reducers: {
  updateOrder: (previousState, { payload }) => {
    return {
      ...previousState,
      taskArray: payload
    }
  },
}
```

**Edit:**

It seems you're trying to deeply clone nested objects.
The following code

```js
const myNewArray = [...myOldArray];
```

does create a new object in memory with all the values from the old array, and mutating the new object won't change the old array.

There is one minor caveat, each of the children within the array will be cloned by reference and not by value.
This means that doing something like this:

```js
const myOldArray = [{a: "hello"}]
const myNewArray = [...myOldArray];
```

will keep a reference to the same `{a: "hello"}` object.

Thus, doing `myNewArray.push("asdf")` will not affect `myOldArray`, but doing `myNewArray[0].a = "goodbye"` will impact on the first item of `myOldArray` as well.

Here's an article with a better explanation https://dev.to/samanthaming/how-to-deep-clone-an-array-in-javascript-3cig

Comment: this does not fix my issue and i dont think why it should. i mentioned that i am using redux toolkit which uses immer to mantain immutability of state. i am updating the proxy state provided by it and not the react state. i think the issue is that `items` is a shallow copy and so it is giving error. but `[...tasks]` should make a new array , not a copy.

Comment: My bad, the answer is mostly a wild guess over what I could infer from looking at the code. It's kinda hard to fully understand what you're trying to do without knowing where/how the `handleOnDragEnd()` function is called and what you're passing as the `result` param, or where you're defining `dispatch`, I'm guessing a `useDispatch()` hook? My point is it's kinda hard to guess.

Comment: Try making a small codesandbox example, it might be easier to communicate the whole scenario. If you want to know whether it's a deep/shallow clone issue, you can also try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nestedArray))`. Array destructuring only goes 1 level deep.

Comment: stringify and then parsing the items worked. it seems that `[...tasks]` is not working as it should . ideally the state binding should be broken as new array is being created. Stringify and parsing worked as a nice hack but still waiting for proper answer. thanks mate

Comment: Glad you solved it mate, here's an article on why you couldn't get it to work with `[...tasks]`. https://dev.to/samanthaming/how-to-deep-clone-an-array-in-javascript-3cig

Essentially the reason is you have objects inside the array, you'd need something like `[...tasks.map((task) => ({...task}))]`  to go 2 levels deep, adding an extra `.map` for each additional level.

Comment: i'm still curious why immer did nothing for immutability

Answer (score 0):

All in one...

```
const copyDeepObject = obj => {
   return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

let copy = copyDeepObject({anything you want to copy}); 
copy.readOnlyProp = "new value";
```